# How to get class field name using ANTLR4?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have java9 source code and I need to extract fields of some classes using antlr4. This is my listener:

```
private static class FieldListener extends Java9BaseListener {

        @Override
        public void enterFieldDeclaration(Java9Parser.FieldDeclarationContext ctx) {
            for (ParseTree subTree : ctx.children) {
                System.out.println(subTree.getText());
            }
            String fieldName = ??????;
        }

    }
```

And this is the code

```
        //Now, let's do some testing. First, we construct the lexer:
        Java9Lexer java9Lexer = new  Java9Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(classContent));

        //Then, we instantiate the parser:
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(java9Lexer);
        Java9Parser parser = new Java9Parser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit();

        //And then, the walker and the listener:
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        walker.walk(new FieldListener(), tree);
```

However, I can only iterate all field tokens but can't get specific token - class fieldName. Could anyone say how to get it?

Comment: Maybe add some context: the grammar you use, the rule that parse the class, and the result of subtree.getText()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no match bullet here. Static semantic analysis is not easy because you have to run around a tree. But it is straight forward. You're going to have to extract the names of the fields by a tree walk from the *variableDeclaratorList*. If you print out a parse tree for some input, you can see that a *variableDeclaratorList* contains a list of *variableDeclarator*, each *variableDeclarator* contains a *variableDeclaratorId*, each *variableDeclaratorId* containing an *identifier* with optional *dims*, and each *identifier* a subtree of tokens *JavaLetter* and more *JavaLetterOrDigit*. How should you compute the attributes of the parse tree? That's up to you. Usually, people compute the synthesized attributes with this Antlr listener framework. You can define a mapping from the node to a data structure containing the attributes, so then when you want the attributes for nodes lower in the tree, you can do a lookup (in this case, maybe resulting in a list of strings for the *variableDeclaratorList*?). You can access a particular node using the accessor function for that child so you don't have to compute attributes from immediate descendants. Look at the generated parser code. You can see what is available, e.g., FieldDeclarationContext.variableDeclaratorList(). Or, if you like, you could call a function to derive the attributes for this specific *variableDeclaratorList* rather than use the Antlr listener framework. 
The [Antlr Listener](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeWalker.java#L23) does not have a short circuit to the walk, so be aware that if you write your own function to walk the *variableDeclaratorList*, you might not want to use a listener *ParseTreeWalker.walk()* and instead use the *ParseTreeVisitor.visit()*.